# 'E492: Not an editor command' when trying to run :RmVimball in VIM?

Tags: vim, plugins, command

I installed the Command-T VIM plugin but it did not work. In fact it made VIM not work. I installed Ruby 1.8.x. I followed the install instructions exactly.

I opened a no-frills version of VIM by running

```
vim -u NONE -i NONE
```

Then from with in VIM I typed

```
:RmVimball command-t-0.8b.vba
```

but all I got was an error message that read

```
E492: Not an editor command: RmVimball command-t-0.8b.vba
```

Also, any other command associated with Vimball comes back with E492. This led me to believe that the vimball.vim plug in was not installed so I installed it, ran the :RmVimball command against the command-t-0.8b.vba vimball and still got error E492.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

**EDIT:**
Here I post the VIM version info from 'vim --version'

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr 16 2010 12:40:58)
Included patches: 1-330
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+cryptv +cscope +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic 
+emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path 
+float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand 
+jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap 
+menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm 
-mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte 
+multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra +perl +postscript 
+printer +profile +python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind 
+signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax 
+tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl +terminfo +termresponse 
+textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual 
+visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup 
+X11 -xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -D_REENTRANT -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -DORBIT2=1 -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12     -Wall -g -O2    -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN  -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE  -I/usr/include/python2.6 -pthread -I/usr/include/tcl8.4  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1  -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux 
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,-E  -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lgio-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0     -lgnomeui-2 -lbonoboui-2 -lgnomevfs-2 -lgnomecanvas-2 -lgnome-2 -lpopt -lbonobo-2 -lbonobo-activation -lORBit-2 -lart_lgpl_2 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lgio-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgconf-2 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lXt -lncurses -lselinux  -lacl -lgpm -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE -lperl -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 -lutil -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.4 -lieee -lruby1.8 -lrt -lm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run vimball if you start vim with the `-u` and `-i` flags set to `NONE`. It skips vimball's autoload files at startup. Consequently, vim thinks you don't have vimball installed (or any other plugin, for that matter). Do you still get the same error when you run vim normally?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned above, I did run 'vim -i NONE -u NONE'. VIM successfully loaded but I got the same error. No plugin is recognized. I will edit my question to include the VIM version info I get from 'vim --version'. Perhaps there could be a clue there.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Running vim with the `-u` and `-i` flags set to `NONE` will not work with vimball. It makes vim skip the directories that load vimball, which is why you are getting the error.

Have you tried using vimball without the aforementioned flags?

Comment: Right you are MM. Thank you. I have uninstalled Command-T but will try installing it again. Conversation continues here https://wincent.com/forums/command-t/topics/425